# Java Subclass uses super.tostring() but not superclass' method in it. Why?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I am doing OOP exercises from https://www3.ntu.edu.sg and I cant figure out one inheritance problem. We have 2 classes: superclass `circle` and subclass `cylinder` `extends` `circle`.

Circle:

```
public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI*radius*radius;
}
public String toString() {
        return "Circle Area: "+this.getArea()";
}
```

Cylinder extends Circle

```
@Override
    public double getArea() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getArea()*2+super.getCircumference()*height;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cylinder["+super.toString+"]"+"Cylinder area="+getArea()+"]";
    }
```

new object type `Cylinder` prints `super.toString()` using `getArea()` from the `Cylinder` class - printing both areas the `cylinder` areas. How can I make it use superclass (`Circles`) `getArea()` in `super.toString`?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't make it because it would be a violation of elementary Java semantics (polymorphism). Your main mistake here is making `Cylinder` a subclass of `Circle`, which it clearly isn't.

Comment: I see. That is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Circle is actually a special case of Cylinder, with zero height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During runtime `this` represents the current instance of the object and this is a `Cylinder` with his `getArea()` method. Therefore inheritance does not help us here.

A workaround can be to change the `Circle` class this way:

```
private double getCircleArea() {
        return Math.PI*radius*radius;
}

public double getArea() {
        return getCircleArea();
}

public String toString() {
        return "Circle Area: " + this.getCircleArea();
}
```

Comment: Ok I am not extending Circle anymore as I think there is an absract class "Shape" with getArea() method which would be overriden. A Cylinder has a base which is a Circle object. So I just use {Circle base = new Circle(radius)} in a Cylinder class and toString works - because there is no more overriding getArea(). Thanks!